# Add custom claims to JWT ACCESS TOKEN using OIDC & WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am interested in adding a custom claim to my JWT access token (not my id token) issued by my WSO2 identity server.  I am following the OpenID connect implicit flow with WSO2.

I attempted to add a custom claim by going to my WSO2 IS console and navigating to  Claims -> Add -> Add Local Claim.  Then I mapped the claim to an attribute in a connected OpenLDAP instance.

[image: Image of Local Claim Setup]

The image above is just an example, the actual claim I'm using maps to an attribute in my OpenLDAP instance that is acting as a secondary user store.

Then I tried to add the claim in my service provider under Service Providers -> List -> Claim Configuration

[image: Image of Service Provider Claim Setup]

However, I'm not seeing that custom claim in my access token granted by my WSO2 Identity Server.

The call to my WSO2 identity server looks like this:

```
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&scope=openid&response_type=token&response_mode=query&nonce=MY_NONCE
```

After entering in the proper credentials, I do not see my custom claim in the token.

Example token payload:

```
{
  "sub": "SUB_REMOVED",
  "aud": "AUD_REMOVED",
  "nbf": 1544053330,
  "azp": "AZP_REMOVED",
  "scope": "openid",
  "iss": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token",
  "groups": [
    "TEST LDAP 3/admin",
    "Internal/everyone"
  ],
  "exp": 1544056930,
  "iat": 1544053330,
  "jti": "JTI_REMOVED"
}
```

Am I missing a step?  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using OIDC, WSO2 IS will send the claims mapped in the `http://wso2.org/oidc/claim` dialect.

So you need to create a claim in the above dialect, mapped to the newly created local claim.
[image]

Then you need to add the newly created claim to the allowed claims list of a scope you are requesting. For this, go to `Manage -> OIDC Scopes -> List` and click on `Add Claims` action of openid scope (or any other scope you are using). Now add the newly created openid claim, click Add and then Finish.

Now try the login flow with a new user.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: hi @Maduranga Siriwardena, is this applicable to non-OIDC scenarios too? If we need to set a custom claim to a non-OIDC access token?