# Return the custom data in the OpenIdConnect token in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We need to send the custom data in OpenId Connect token returned by the WSO2 server.

When I will decode the JWT token we need something like as follows:- We need "data" attribute with json data.

{
"at_hash": "test",
"sub": "tester",
"data": { "user_account": "testlogin" },
......
}

How can I configure or do the same?
Note: **user_account** value should be the logged in user.

Thanks,
Tushar

Comment: Do you want to include all the custom user attributes as a JSON object value respective to a key named "data" Or else is it fine to add each custom attribute as a first-class key in the JWT itself?

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 Identity Server, we can write custom claim provider as an OSGI service to add new claims to ID token in OpenID Connect protocol. According to the current implementation, we have an extension point to write a custom claim provider which can be plugged in to inject claims into ID Token.

Please refer following resources for more information[1][2][3]

[1]https://ganganichamika.medium.com/how-to-write-custom-claim-provider-in-wso2-identity-server-c1d2c9814b84

[2]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/user-mgt/write-a-custom-claim-handler/

[3][Add custom claims to JWT ACCESS TOKEN using OIDC & WSO2 IS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642834/add-custom-claims-to-jwt-access-token-using-oidc-wso2-is)